# Start Activator using cmd

Tags: playframework, cmd, typesafe-activator

I would like to know how to create a bat file that changes directory and start activator

I tried without success..

```
cmd /k cd c:\Users\user\project & activator -jvm-debug 9999 run
cmd /k cd c:\Users\user\project && activator -jvm-debug 9999 run
cmd /k cd c:\Users\user\project ; activator -jvm-debug 9999 run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd /k` will run `cd c:\Users\user\project` and immediately to the cmd prompt. So the second part `activator -jvm-debug 9999 run` will never run.

You need to remove `cmd /k`  from your batch file.

Use instead the following batch file:

```
@echo off
cd c:\Users\user\project && activator -jvm-debug 9999 run
```

- This will run the the first command `cd c:\Users\user\project`
- If the first command succeeds it will then run the second command `activator -jvm-debug 9999 run`

Note `activator` must be in `%path%` for this to work.

---

Source [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

> Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable
>   program.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `CMD [charset] [options]`
>
> `CMD [charset] [options] [/C Command]`
>
> `CMD [charset] [options] [/K Command]`
>
> **Options**
>
> `/C` Run Command and then terminate
>
> `/K` Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
>             This is useful for testing, to examine variables

---

Source [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

> `commandA && commandB` Run `commandA`, if it succeeds then run
>   `commandB`

Comment: I want this to use it in eclipse, but eclipse console dont accept the ctr + d to stop. For now I'll use this bat pinned to the taskbar.